# Why does VS2010 allow you to type in the function parameter followed by a colon?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, intellisense

I'm getting Intellisense in .NET 4 that is allowing me to do something with function parameters such as "category:" below in VS2010.  What does this mean, and what can I do with this?

[image]

Comment: it's example of named argument the feature of C# 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's for the [Named & Optional Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx) feature of .NET 4.0.

`category` is a parameter in one of the [`Debug.Write`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.write.aspx) overloaded methods.

Answer (score 1):

[Named and optional arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx) were introduced in C# 4.  These arguments allow developers to write fewer method overloads.

They are also helpful when dealing with COM interop scenarios.  Following are examples from MSDN.

Before optional arguments:

```
excelApp.get_Range("A1", "B4").AutoFormat(myFormat, Type.Missing, 
    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

After optional arguments:

```
excelApp.Range["A1", "B4"].AutoFormat( Format: myFormat );
```